# How to install NodeJs IntelliJ CE plugin?

Tags: node.js, macos, intellij-idea, homebrew

Im using OSX + IntelliJ which was install via brew cask.

I was unable to install the NodeJS plugin.

It is not listed in the Preferences | Plugins (not via install JetBrains plugins nor Browse repositories)

I've downloded it from here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=idea&

Extract it and got a NodeJS directory.
I've move it to:
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/Contents/plugins

But still it doesn't loaded...

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *Node.js* plugin is not supported in the Community Edition. It is a feature available only in the Ultimate Edition (and WebStorm). See the [IntelliJ IDEA Edition Comparison Matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) page for more info.